# How to capture event when user proceeds to next input on tablet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

Is there an event, perhaps in jQuery Mobile, for capturing tablet's keyboard action that is meant to accept entered text and proceed to next text input? It occurs usually under 'Ok' or 'Next'.

Comment: Study `focus`and `blur` event

Comment: I'm interesed specifically in event after tapping 'Next' but **before** focusing on next input.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to `focusout` event, which is triggered using next/previous buttons.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
   $("element").on("focusout", function () {
      /* code */
   });
});
```